# Sending client side changes in GridView to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am moving my gridview rows up and down using jquery but it does not go back to server as it is done at client side. what to do? 
here is the code to move rows -

```
 $(".up,.down").click(function () {
                var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
                var rowIndex = row.index();
                if ($(this).is(".up")) {
                    if (rowIndex != 1) {
                        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
                    }
                } else {
                    row.insertAfter(row.next());
                }

            });
```

my gridview is using template fields. this is the gridview -

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVRequestedLOE" runat="server" CellPadding="3" CssClass="cssDefaultDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="False" AllowPaging="false" DataKeyNames="GraphicLicenseTextRightsLOEID" Width="95%" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellSpacing="0" EmptyDataText="No details to display.">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="cssDefaultDataGridAltRow" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="cssDefaultDataGridHeader" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No details to display.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img id="imgBtnUp" src="../images/arrow1up_blue.gif" alt="../images/arrow1up_blue.gif" title="Move LOE Row up the list" class="up" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                <img id="imgBtnDown" src="../images/arrow1down_blue.gif" alt="../images/arrow1down_blue.gif" title="Move LOE Row down the list" class="down" style="cursor: pointer;" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text Product Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTextProductType" Width="160px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Territory">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTerritory" Width="160px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Including Audio" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FooterStyle-Wrap="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludingAudio" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("IncludingAudio")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIncludingAudio_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Audio Only" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FooterStyle-Wrap="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAudioOnly" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("AudioOnly")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkAudioOnly_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reproducible By Design" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FooterStyle-Wrap="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReproducibleByDesign" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("ReproducibleByDesign")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Language">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLanguage" Width="100px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LOEQuantity")%>' Width="80px" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="(Qty)Not Specified" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FooterStyle-Wrap="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUnlimitedQuantity" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("UnlimitedQuantity")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkUnlimitedQuantity_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty Silent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FooterStyle-Wrap="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkQtySilent" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("SilentQuantity")%>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkQtySilent_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Est. Price $">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstimatedPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EstimatedPrice")%>' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gratis">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGratis" Width="100px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDeleteLOE" ImageUrl="../images/trashcan.gif" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("GraphicLicenseTextRightsLOEID")%>' OnClientClick="Javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this LOE?')" CommandName="DeleteLOE" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: you cannot. gridview is a server side control